# Why does Thonny get this error?

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I am currently programming a Raspberry Pi Pico with the explorer base, and I am using the examples at https://github.com/pimoroni/pimoroni-pico (**NOTE:** I am using MicroPython in the Thonny IDE to program this). I have figured out how to use the push buttons on the board, but whenever I run my code, it gets this error:
[image: Thonny error]
code:

[image: Code]

(image used for better readability)

Comment: Looks like you have to call pico.init(buffer) to initialise the display. https://github.com/pimoroni/pimoroni-pico/blob/main/micropython/examples/pico_explorer/buttons.py

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... include the actual text instead ... delete the pictures

Comment: I do not see how this helps. This is showing to use a ByteArray on the display, and not the button.

Comment: Never mind, me just being dumb. The code worked! Thank you. Please post an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: Rename /home/pi/pico.py to ANY other name. Your program is trying to load itself when it attempts  to load the pico library function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have to call `pico.init(buffer)` (where `buffer` is an existing `bytearray`) to initialise the display.

https://github.com/pimoroni/pimoroni-pico/blob/main/micropython/examples/pico_explorer/buttons.py